# Multiple target variables are causing problem: Invalid argument: required broadcastable shapes

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network, multilabel-classification

I'm trying to feed multiple target variables through tensorflow dataset, it generates error regarding broadcastable shapes. Each output variable consists of 9 different classes.

```
tf_train_dataset = train_dataset["train"].to_tf_dataset(
    columns=["attention_mask", "input_ids"],
    label_cols=[ 'cohesion', 'syntax', 'vocabulary','phraseology',
                'grammar', 'conventions'],#["labels"],
    shuffle=True,
    collate_fn=data_collator,
    batch_size=8,
)
tf_test_dataset = train_dataset["test"].to_tf_dataset(
    columns= ["attention_mask", "input_ids"],
    
    label_cols=[ 'cohesion', 'syntax', 'vocabulary',
                 'phraseology', 'grammar', 'conventions'],#["labels"],,#["labels"],
    shuffle=False,
    collate_fn=data_collator,
    batch_size=8,
    )
```

```
for data in tf_train_dataset.take(1):
    print (data)
```

```
({'input_ids': <tf.Tensor: shape=(8, 512), dtype=int64, numpy=
array([[    1, 16237, 47663, ...,     0,     0,     0],
       [    1,   325,   269, ...,     0,     0,     0],
       [    1,   273,   266, ...,     0,     0,     0],
       ...,
       [    1,  7593,   411, ...,  2274,   403,     2],
       [    1,   329,  1253, ...,     0,     0,     0],
       [    1,   879,   355, ...,     0,     0,     0]])>, 'attention_mask': <tf.Tensor: shape=(8, 512), dtype=int64, numpy=
array([[1, 1, 1, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       ...,
       [1, 1, 1, ..., 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, ..., 0, 0, 0]])>}, {'cohesion': <tf.Tensor: shape=(8,), dtype=float32, numpy=array([4., 3., 4., 2., 5., 4., 2., 6.], dtype=float32)>, 'syntax': <tf.Tensor: shape=(8,), dtype=float32, numpy=array([4., 4., 3., 2., 4., 4., 2., 4.], dtype=float32)>, 'vocabulary': <tf.Tensor: shape=(8,), dtype=float32, numpy=array([3., 3., 4., 4., 5., 4., 3., 4.], dtype=float32)>, 'phraseology': <tf.Tensor: shape=(8,), dtype=float32, numpy=array([3., 4., 4., 3., 4., 3., 2., 4.], dtype=float32)>, 'grammar': <tf.Tensor: shape=(8,), dtype=float32, numpy=array([5., 5., 3., 4., 5., 3., 2., 5.], dtype=float32)>, 'conventions': <tf.Tensor: shape=(8,), dtype=float32, numpy=array([5., 2., 3., 3., 6., 5., 2., 5.], dtype=float32)>})
```

```
import tensorflow as tf
# build 2 input layers to Bert Model where name needs to match the input values in the dataset
tf.random.set_seed(123)
tf.keras.backend.clear_session()
input_ids = tf.keras.Input(shape=(SEQ_LEN,), name = 'input_ids', dtype='int32')
#token_type_ids = tf.keras.Input(shape=(SEQ_LEN,), name = 'token_type_ids', dtype='int32')
attention_mask = tf.keras.Input(shape=(SEQ_LEN,), name = 'attention_mask', dtype='int32')
base_outputs = base_model.deberta({"input_ids":input_ids,
                              "attention_mask": attention_mask})
#embedings = base_model.layers[0](input_ids, attention_mask)[0] # token_type_ids
last_hidden_state = base_outputs[0]
#Original Author: Ferry Djaja
#https://djajafer.medium.com/multi-class-text-classification-with-keras-and-lstm-4c5525bef592
X= MeanPool()(last_hidden_state, attention_mask)
#X = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5)(embedings)
#X = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(X)
#X = tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(256))(last_hidden_state)
#X = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5)(X)
outputs = []
for i in range(6):
    y = tf.keras.layers.Dense(9, activation='softmax', name=f"{index2label[i]}")(X)
    outputs.append(y)

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[input_ids, attention_mask], outputs=outputs) #token_type_ids
```

```
history = model.fit(tf_train_dataset,
                    validation_data=tf_test_dataset,
                    verbose=1,
                    epochs=3,)
```

```
InvalidArgumentError:  required broadcastable shapes
     [[node gradient_tape/SparseCategoricalFocalLoss/add_2 (defined at <timed exec>:5) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_245563]
```

Comment: This problem occurres when your number of classes doesn't match the shape of the output layer. So, your last layer contains 9 as an output shape but you have 8 types. This may be the case.

Comment: Hi @Muhammad, As mentioned above, the number of units should be equal to the number of classes in the last(output) layer. Hence, change the last layer(Dense) to `tf.keras.layers.Dense(8, activation='softmax', name=f"{index2label[i]}")(X)` and let us know if the issue still persists. Thanks you!

Comment: I already checked against the number of classes set to 8, and it won't work. Basically, 8 is a batch size.